# Replace carriage return in SQL Server Compact edition

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm trying to create a query on a Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4 database that replaces carriage return characters in certain columns. Typically you would do

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(some_col, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

but apparently the CHAR function isn't supported. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Compact only supports Unicode, maybe you can use NCHAR ?